# How to send compressed (deflated) SVG via Apache2?

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, svg, apache2

I have specified the following attributes in my site's `.htaccess` file:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
DeflateCompressionLevel 9
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
```

However, my SVG asset is not being sent in compressed form:

```
$ curl https://example.org/assets/svg/asset.svg --silent -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" --write-out "${size_download}\n" --output /dev/null                 
152655                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
$ curl https://example.org/assets/svg/asset.svg --silent --write-out "%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null
152655
```

I verified that this asset (`asset.svg`) is being sent with MIME type `image/svg+xml` using Chrome, but using the Web Developer tools, this specific file is not being compressed when sent to the client.

Adding other MIME types to the `.htaccess` file is successful (e.g., adding `text/html` compresses the HTML assets).

This seems specific to how SVG data are handled. What else can I try or troubleshoot to get SVG compression working?

Comment: Can you do `curl --head https://example.org/assets/svg/asset.svg`?

Comment: Yes, this returns `Content-Type: image/svg+xml`, among other headers.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If Apache doesn't know the mime type of the file (here image/svg+xml), you need to tell it specifically (not needed in most Apaches):

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

Now when Apache knows about the filetype, just add this to deflate it:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
```

For more information see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you sure your server reads the .htaccess? I just tested it on my Apache2 and here it works fine for SVG files.

Comment: I think that it does, because it is able to compress other assets, whose MIME types I specified in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Actually, I am wrong. I had `AllowOverride None` in the parent conf file, as well as output filters that compressed files with the other MIME types. Once I changed that directive to `AllowOverride All`, things worked fine. Wonderful, cheers!

Comment: Since Apache 2.4, the [docs for mod_deflate state](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html): "The **gzip** encoding is the only one supported to ensure complete compatibility with old browser implementations. The **deflate encoding is not supported**, please check the zlib's documentation for a complete explanation."
deflate is broken in many browsers.

Comment: I think this answer could be simplified. My **Apache 2.4.25** already ships with a `/etc/apache2/magic` file knowing how to identify SVGs, and I don't needed to add an _AddType_ directive to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` to have that "passed around" internally. All I did was adding `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml` to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf` and Apache2 served it compressed. (As @rainer-rillke commented, DEFLATE seems to be a synonym for GZIP these days.)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is due to the plus sign in the MIME type, which may need escaping in the AddOutputFilterByType directive. You can also try using the [AddOutputFilter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#AddOutputFilter) directive instead, to process all files with a certain extension:

```
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE svg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help, but I appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

**Best option I found is to compress everything except images, which mod_deflate isn't able to handle it.**

add following lines to `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \

\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|exe)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

**If u want to see logging of what was compressed add the following also:**

```
DeflateFilterNote Input instream

DeflateFilterNote Output outstream

DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate

CustomLog logs/deflate_log deflate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the type as well. Some configurations seem to need it for various reasons. .svg works fine for me using the `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml`.
Try also adding the mime type.

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

On some inspection in `error.log` of my apache `httpd`, It looks like we should not specify `DeflateCompressionLevel` here...

```
[Mon Feb 03 23:56:52 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/.htaccess:DeflateCompressionLevel not allowed here
```

... So I have removed compression level and put only the
`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml`, which makes it work correctly.

Sample outputs...

with deflate...

```
don@don-NE56R:/var/www$ curl http://mydaddy.com:81/circle.svg -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" --write-out "${size_download}\n"
ݶٮ;��uCL*j��z�9.�����#�_]#���̊Ve��p��$�y�D���h��þ ��|�XeP��R�
```

and without deflate..

```
don@don-NE56R:/var/www$ curl http://mydaddy.com:81/circle.svg  --write-out "${size_download}\n"
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. My error log does not report any errors with DeflateCompressionLevel, either. Weird issue! Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: I am surprised then. My machine or your machine must be weird.