# Gzip working for html, but not javascript or css (Apache)

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, gzip

On my site, the html files are gzipped.

However, the javascript, css, and svg files are not.

The server uses Apache/2.2.22.

I'm using the .htaccess file from HTML5boilerplate. Here's the relevant section:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"

</IfModule>
```

For what it's worth - it's not related to subfolders. If I put a file named "test.html" in the main directory - it's gzipped. If I rename it "test.js" - it's not.

***[UPDATE]***

So, this was dumb.

As I mentioned, I was using the .htaccess file from html5boilerplate.

When I looked at that closely, I noticed these notes:

```
# (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
# enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
# and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
# the core directives.
```

This applies to me, since the server uses Apache/2.2.22.

Sure enough, as soon as I removed `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`, everything worked as it should have (i.e., the javascript, css, and other file types included in that list were **all** gzipped.

I'll leave this question, just in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did.

Comment: Check the rest of your config for "gzip-only-text/html"?
Or other SetOutputFilter?
Or perhaps this .htaccess is not read at all and defalte is setup elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was dumb.

As I mentioned, I was using the .htaccess file from html5boilerplate.

When I looked at that closely, I noticed these notes:

```
# (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
# enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
# and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
# the core directives.
```

This applies to me, since the server uses Apache/2.2.22.

Sure enough, as soon as I removed `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`, everything worked as it should have (i.e., the javascript, css, and other file types included in that list were **all** gzipped.

I'll leave this answer, just in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed something:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21533084/1491007

Best, 
Ralf